# Azure AD Authentication on Third Party AD Tenant

Tags: authentication, azure

In my case there is already an existing tenant of an organization. We are supposed to use that AAD tenant for authentication purpose since it already has the users needed to authenticate. Howeever I do not have the Global admin rights on that AAD tenant. I can create an application on that AAD tenant. I have also created a website that uses that AAD tenant to authenticate. When I run the website in browser, it redirects to a login page. I am able to authenticate myself of that AAD tenant and can see the home page of the website. But, when my colleagues try ot login using the same url for the website, it redirects to a login page, however when they enter username and password it gives the following error:

"AADSTS90093: This operation can only be performed by an administrator. Sign out and sign in as an administrator or contact one of your organization's administrators."

Kindly suggest a solution for the issue.

Note: I am using VS 2013 for this project.

Comment: Same here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Juan: Finally figured out the solution. You need to request the global administrator of the Azure AD to enable WS Federation for your application on the respective AD tenant.

Comment: How does the admin enable WS Federation?

Comment: Thanks, that was the solution